# Required a solution in searching string in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string `"platform:17.01.02"` and I want to search for `"17.01.02"` which I'm giving through a variable.

```
a = "platform:17.01.02"
b = "17.01.02" (has to taken from user)

a.search(/b/)
```

The above statement search for "b" and not for variable value "b". Can any one help how can i search that?

Comment: `b` doesn't look like a regex, so you should not use `search`

Comment: `a.search(b)` is enough here

Comment: You are looking for [`a.indexOf(b)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: a.search(b) worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var a = "platform:17.01.02";
var b = "17.01.02";

console.log(a.search(new RegExp(b))); //9
```

If you just want to know if `a` contains `b`, use:

```
a.indexOf(b) >= 0
```

Comment: that will yield unexpected results when the user accidentally types in regex metacharacters